# In c# MVC ... Is it possible that I can mark part of a string as red color?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

`.ForMember(d => d.Name, op => op.MapFrom(s => s.Name1 + s.Name2 + s.Name3))`)

I have a above mapping in one of my code. I was wondering is it even possible that I can display name3 in red color? Is yes what is the possibility?

Thank you for you help everyone.

Comment: what do you mean red color? show your model & view page

Comment: with asp.net MVC built in? nope. custom html, yes

Answer (score 3):

That mapping is from one type to another and if you are looking for a way to do it there, then no there is no way and it is for good reasons: This is a UI concern and it does not even belong there.

You need to create a model with the property `Name3` and whatever else you need. Send it to your view as the model for the view. In the view, you can apply any style you want to the html tag that will be used to display the property. For example:

```
<div class="text-danger">
     @Model.Name3
</div>
```

Or you can use:

```
@Html.LabelFor( model => model.Name3, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "text-danger" })
```

Or instead of `text-danger`, you can use your own CSS class.

And just an FYI, `Name3` is not a very descriptive property name.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark things in Color but only when you display it in a TextBox or similar. To do that you can put the part you want into a Span and Style that Red.